# Почему Idea не создает папку scr и файл pom.xml пустой?

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

создавая новый maven проект idea не создает каталог src и файл pom.xml пуст, как можно решить эту проблему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам maven скачан. Но если вводить команды то будут показываться ошибки.Также тема данной ошибки была открыта давно (видел такой же вопрос на habar). Но если сделать базовую структуру pow.xml то все ошибки уйдут и всё будет работать,если есть решение чтобы сама iDE всё инициализировало как надо то в путь,но мне больше волнует почему не сформировалась структура проекта.Прошу подселитесь решением вы поможете многим людям :)